# Getting Create Process error=206, The filename or extension is too long Exception if i add spring-cloud-starter-sleuth

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graphql, spring-cloud

I am using spring boot v2.2.7 with Graphql Starter. I am getting some above exception while adding the spring-cloud-starter-sleuth. if I remove this library everything works fine.

I tried with downgrading the version. It works fine in spring parent 2.1.9  and Greenwich cloud version but if I upgrade spring to 2.2.7 and cloud Hoxton this issue I am getting.

And also if I remove the spring-cloud-starter-sleuth library everything works fine.

here are logs:

```
E:\xxxxx\backend\xxxxx-sfstr-query-service>mvn spring-boot:run -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------< com.xxxxx.business.query:xxxxx-sfstr-query-service >-------
[INFO] Building xxxxx-sfstr-query-service 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.7.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ xxxxx-sfstr-query-service >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ xxxxx-sfstr-query-service ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ xxxxx-sfstr-query-service ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ xxxxx-sfstr-query-service ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\xxxxx\backend\xxxxx-sfstr-query-service\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ xxxxx-sfstr-query-service ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.7.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ xxxxx-sfstr-query-service <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.7.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ xxxxx-sfstr-query-service ---
[INFO] Attaching sfstrs: []
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.774 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-11T22:42:30+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.7.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project xxxxx-sfstr-query-service: Could not exec java: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\java.exe" (in directory "E:\xxxxx\backend\xxxxx-sfstr-query-service"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.7.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project xxxxx-sfstr-query-service: Could not exec java
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not exec java
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.forkJvm (RunMojo.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.runWithForkedJvm (RunMojo.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm (AbstractRunMojo.java:292)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:257)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute (AbstractRunMojo.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\java.exe" (in directory "E:\xxxxx\backend\xxxxx-sfstr-query-service"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.RunProcess.run (RunProcess.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.forkJvm (RunMojo.java:116)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.runWithForkedJvm (RunMojo.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm (AbstractRunMojo.java:292)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:257)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute (AbstractRunMojo.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create (Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init> (ProcessImpl.java:420)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start (ProcessImpl.java:151)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.RunProcess.run (RunProcess.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.forkJvm (RunMojo.java:116)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.runWithForkedJvm (RunMojo.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm (AbstractRunMojo.java:292)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:257)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute (AbstractRunMojo.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

here is pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xxxxx.business.query</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxxx-dfsdf-query-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>xxxxx-dfsdf-query-service</name>
    <description>xxxxx dfsdf Query Service</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR4</spring-cloud.version>
        <xxxxx.version>1.0</xxxxx.version>
        <jjwt.version>0.9.1</jjwt.version>
        <json.version>20180813</json.version>
        <mysql.version>8.0.11</mysql.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.6</commons-io.version>
        <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
        <commons-pool2.version>2.5.0</commons-pool2.version>
            <redis.version>3.3.0</redis.version>
        <velocity.version>1.7</velocity.version>
        <velocity-tools.version>2.0</velocity-tools.version>
        <logstash-logback-encoder.version>5.3</logstash-logback-encoder.version>
        <httpclient.version>4.5.6</httpclient.version>
        <graphql-spring-boot-starter.version>5.0.2</graphql-spring-boot-starter.version>
        <graphql-java-tools.version>5.2.4</graphql-java-tools.version>
        <jaxb-runtime.version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</jaxb-runtime.version>
        <env>local</env>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Start: Spring Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End: Spring Libraries -->

        <!-- Adding JAXB Runtime since it is not shipped with JDK 9+ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb-runtime.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>


        <!-- Start: Graph QL Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${graphql-spring-boot-starter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${graphql-spring-boot-starter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${graphql-java-tools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End: Graph QL Libraries -->

        <!-- Start: xxxxx Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-entity</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-redis</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-util</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx.model</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-model</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-mongo</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-common-service</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-common-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-common-security</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-antivirus-service</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxx.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxx-docrepo-service</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End: xxxxx Libraries -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>${json.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Json Web Token Binary -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logstash Log Encoder -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>${logstash-logback-encoder.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-pool2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-pool2.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>${redis.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- velocity -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>${velocity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${velocity-tools.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Start: Spring Boot and Security Test Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End: Spring Boot and Security Test Libraries -->

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>xxxxx-dfsdf-query-service</finalName>
        <filters>
            <filter>${env}-build.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
                <configuration>
                    <release>${java.version}</release>
                     <fork>false</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Automatic-Module-Name>com.xxxxx.business.query.dfsdf</Automatic-Module-Name>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Why this issue is coming..? is there any problem with library?

Comment: This is an issue with your OS. Likely windows

Comment: yes i have the same error how to solve ?

Answer (score 0):

if your windows user you to change your maven  m2 repository path to the shortest path. default its pointing to  some nested folder in C directory, so change it to some shortest path